# The data is not added into linked list and display correctly. Why?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a system which store data using linked list in GUI form.
I have encountered some problem when it comes to store and display the linked list. Looks like after I input the data, it did not stored into the linked list

What I am doing is a library system, so what I need is store the book name, author name, ISBN number and number of copies of book into a single node in linked list. The information are come from user input such as jTextField1. My lecturer had taught me how to insert single data but now I need to insert multiple data.

I have recreate the constructor and the getter method in Node class and change it in the LinkedList class as well. But for some reason the data seems not to add into the LinkedList, when I display the list in TextArea, all it shows was NULL but not the data I just input. Why is that?

This is my Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;
    Node next;

    Node()
    {
        name = null;
        author = null;
        isbn = 0;
        number = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    Node(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.number = number;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    int getisbn()
    {
        return isbn;
    }

    int getnumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    Node getNext()
    {
        return next;   
    }

    void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next=next;
    }
}
```

This is my Linked list class:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node node = new Node();
    Node head;

    LinkedList()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public void addNode(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(name, author, isbn, number);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Node added to the list.");
　　    }
    }

    public String displayNode()
    {
        Node current = head;
        String output = "";

        while(current!= null)
        {
            output+="Book Name: "+current.getName()+" Author: "+current.getAuthor()+" ISBN Number: "+current.getisbn()+" Number of copies: "+current.getnumber();
            current=current.getNext();
        }

        return(output+"NULL");
    }
```

And this is what I have in my AddBook JFrame:

```
public class AddBook extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
    static String name;
    static String author;
    static int isbn;
    static int number;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.addNode(jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));        
}          
}
```

Another JFrame with display:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    jTextArea1.setText(list.displayNode());
}
```

The Data class:

```
public class Data {
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;

    public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)
    {

    }
}
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Think of a node like about a bucket that can contain any data, not only a simple number (as a majority of tutorials describe).*

Instead of the `int num` field in your `Node` class, you could use any reference type you want to, for example, a `List<Integer>`:

```
public class Node  {
    List<Integer> data;
    ...
}
```

In that case, you need to rewrite the constructor and the getter as well (by changing a parameter type and a return type respectively).

Another good solution that doesn't break [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would be using a wrapper class (e.g. `Data`):

```
class Data {
    private Integer i;
    private String s;
}
```

Comment: I see, but I have String and integer in my data, will the node contain both of them as well ? Or it must be same data type ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will, but it's not a good idea. It's better to create a wrapper class like Data and keep them there

Comment: Node is responsible for keeping only references and data, but data itself can contain any information (the single responsibility principle)

Comment: I see, I rewrite the constructor and getter, it will add but when comes to display there's problem, its like it did not add to the linked list... I will update the code. Thanks

Comment: Code updated. Please help me take a look on what's wrong with the code if that's okay. Thanks!

Comment: @Acetamide, first, the `addNode` method should take a node as a parameter

Comment: But when I called the method, what should I put in the parameter ? The list.addNode(.....), the Node head as well ?

Comment: @Acetamide, `list.addNode(new Node(new Data(...)))`

Comment: It gives me error: Cannot find symbol in location class AddBook, should I add the Node newNode = new Node(...) at the class AddBook as well ?

Comment: `list.addNode(new Node(new Data(jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()))))`

Comment: I don't have the new data class, so I write it like this: `list.addNode(jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()),new Node());` but still display NULL to me when I display it.

Comment: it is because you don't change the list in the `jButton1ActionPerformed`

Comment: you'd better create this class

Comment: Okay will do, I should assign those variables in this Data class right ? Like `name = jTextField2.getText()` ? Thanks!

Comment: @Acetamide, yes, it takes some time, but it's important to write right code at once

Comment: @Acetamide, no, the `Data` class should have own all args constructor

Comment: I create the class already, should I open another class for it or just create it under the Node class ? I open another class for it, and called it at AddBook class, then errors: No suitable constructor found for Node(Data). I have updated the Data class code in the question, really sorry for troubling you this much! Thanks!

Comment: @Acetamide, not a problem, you should define a constructor that takes a `Data` instance

Comment: @Acetamide, these fields shouldn't be inside the `AddBook` class, just create a new class `Data` and put four fields there (without `static`, of course)

Comment: So that means my Node constructor have to take the `Data` contructor ? I have create a new class for Data and have the contrustor `public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)` but inside I haven't put a thing yet.

Comment: @Acetamide, yes

Comment: Hmm sorry about this but what do I need to change at Node class in order to achieve that ? And in the Data contructor I don't have to write anything ? Thanks.

Comment: @Acetamide, Sorry, but I'm afraid we can't continue the discussion in style like "what line should I paste here to make it working". You should understand what you are doing. Your task is writing 3 classes with all arguments constructors and corresponding getters/setters. Then after your list gets created, add some nodes and display them. If this list is common for few classes, it makes sense to move it to a separate class and mark as static, if it is not, then make the list as an instance field. Your problem is non-understanding how instances interact with each other.

Comment: @Acetamide, It is hard to answer questions like "And in the Data contructor I don't have to write anything?" because it is a base without which we can't move on. Try to read and understand, then if there will any concrete questions, I will respond.

Comment: I understand, I will read something about the instances and linked list, thanks for helping this much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create sme kind of "box" class for data and replace it with `int num;`, eg:

```
public class Box {
    String name;
    String author;

    Box(String name, String author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

You treat it in Node and LinkedList just like your int, but inserting looks like this:

```
yourList.add(new Box("book", "author"));
```

If you want to use your list for different types, you have to learn about generics, for example from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: I see, but I have to retrieve the data from user input into jTextField, so in the insertion can I do like this: yourList.add(new Box(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText())); ? Thanks.

Comment: @Acetamide Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional attributes to your `Node` class as shown below:

```
    public class Node{

    String bookName, author;
    int isbn, copies;
    Node next;
   ...
```

Now you can have get() and set() methods for all of these attributes for each `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

The `head` of a linked list should point to the top element. Thus, in `addNode`, what you should be modifying is the `node` attribute.

```
public class LinkedList
{
   Node node;
   Node head = new Node();

   LinkedList()
   {
      node = null;
   }
...
```

Furthermore, adding a node should should make the previous node's `next` point to the new node created, in order to connect the new node to the rest of the linked list.

The node with the `null` next marks the tail node, in which we will connect the newly created node.

You can do so by looping through the lists' nodes until a `null` next is found,
or by storing the tail node as an attribute of the linked list.

```
public class LinkedList
{
   Node node;
   Node head = new Node();
   Node tail; // add tail as attribute
...


public void addNode(int item)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(item, null);
    node = newNode; //head = newNode;

    tail.setNext(newNode); // connects the new node
    tail = newNode; // makes the new node the new tail

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Node added to the list.");
}
```

Comment: Got it, but now I have display problem as if the data is not adding to the linked list, do you mind help me take a look what was wrong ? I have edited the question already. Thanks!